# Uploading CA-Signed CRT to Salesforce?

Tags: integration, callout, security, authentication, httprequest

I have an existing CA-Signed Certificate (CRT) given to me by my client, and it is needed to be able to make callouts to their external system. I have not found a way to be able to upload a CRT to Salesforce, since the Import from Keystore option only allows you to upload JKS formatted files. All they provided was the CRT file.

What can I do to upload this certificate to Salesforce?

Comment: Was this certificate created in Salesforce and then sent to CA Authority for signing?

Comment: @JayantDas No, this was a certificate that was provided to us by the Client

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000266978&language=en_US&type=1), seems like you need that.

Answer (score 0):

No way to upload a .crt file to Salesforce. You need .jks for that.